# How to change font size of R^2 on scatterplot?

Tags: r

I have created a scatterplot and have included my R^2 value on the figure. However, I want to reduce the text size of the R^2 value but cant seem to work out how to do it. My code is below.

```
ggplot(Gully, aes(x = Downstream, y = Depth))+
  geom_point(size = 0.5)+
  stat_smooth(method= "lm", col = "black", sixe = 0.5) + 
  theme_bw()+
  theme_classic()+
  stat_regline_equation(label.y = -7, aes(label = ..rr.label.., size = 4))+
  labs(y = "Decline in waterhole depth (m)", x = "Downstream distance (km)")+
  theme(text=element_text(size=8, family = "Arial"))
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Thakyou
Marita

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to map a variable with level "4" to the size aesthetic, which you do if you put `size = 4` in `aes()`.

You can simply set a `size = 4` for the text size if you set the argument inside `stat_regline_equation` but outside of `aes()`.

In absence of any minimal example data in your question, here comes an example from the `stat_regline_equation` help page.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

set.seed(4321)
x <- 1:100
y <- (x + x^2 + x^3) + rnorm(length(x), mean = 0, sd = mean(x^3) / 4)
my.data <- data.frame(x, y, group = c("A", "B"),
                      y2 = y * c(0.5,2), block = c("a", "a", "b", "b"))

# Fit polynomial regression line and add labels
formula <- y ~ poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE)
ggplot(my.data, aes(x, y2, color = group)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(aes(fill = group, color = group), method = "lm", formula = formula) +
  stat_regline_equation(
    aes(label =  paste(..eq.label.., ..adj.rr.label.., sep = "~~~~")),
    formula = formula, size = 8 ## size argument outside of aes()
  ) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>